# Import Jenkins WorkflowScript class

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

Instead of using def in my groovy scripts, I would like to be able to import the WorkflowScript class.

Instead of:

```
def script
```

I want:

```
WorkflowScript script
```

I want that because when I want to pass a script to a function, like `get_branch(script)` it usually crash. For a weird reason it works with constructor, not methods.

For my IDE, I would also need to be able to get the dependency, which I do not find on maven, any way for that ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think this class is build dynamically to attach into it all available plugin extensions. But I think you can use super class for `WorkflowScript` - `CpsScript`:

```
import org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScript
```

More information about the `CpsScript` can be found here: https://javadoc.jenkins.io/plugin/workflow-cps/org/jenkinsci/plugins/workflow/cps/package-tree.html

Answer (score 0):

One more option I have found

```
Script script
```

And you don't need to import anything more.